# How to tell whether a PDF is tagged

Tags: php, pdf, accessibility, tcpdf, fpdf

Is it possible to determine programatically whether a PDF is "tagged" (for accessibility)? I'm using PHP, and would like (if possible) to simply read a PDF file and return true if tagged, false if not.

I've looked at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/home.php) and [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php), but it isn't clear to me whether either can extract this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the official ISO PDF-1.7 specification (in the copy available for free from the Adobe website), I read on page 574:

> *"A Tagged PDF document shall also contain a mark information dictionary (see Table 321) with a value of **true** for the **Marked** entry."*

To me that means...

1. ...you'll have to parse the PDF structure and
2. ...look for the *document catalogue*
3. ...where there should be a *MarkInfo* entry
4. ...specifying a *mark information dictionary*
5. ...which should contain a key named *Marked* with a boolean value of *true* for tagged PDF.

Comment: That seems to always appear as "<</Marked true>>", findable by searching the PDF as a string. Thanks !

Comment: @Terrill Thomson: Yes, it may work for 95% or more of all tagged PDFs. But don't rely on just grepping for that string if you need high reliability. (Also, one could easily create such a PDF which declares itself as tagged this way, but in practice doesn't 'keep the promise' and does fail all compliance checks...

Comment: @TerrillThompson: The document catalog can be compressed.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can go further with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php) (check all **PDF_get_xx** functions).
You will also need [this](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-8.0.4-API-reference.pdf) as reference.

Based on this:

```
Characteristics of a properly tagged PDF:

    - The PDF file includes a logical reading order for its content
    - Images are given correct alternate descriptions
    - Tables are correctly tagged to represent the table structure
    - Form-fields are authored to promote their utility to screen-readers
    - Represents text as Unicode to clear up composition irregularities such as soft
      and hard hyphens
```

you might get further.